# How to use a named router-outlet inside a primary router-outlet?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a primary router-outlet (inside my side-nav component) and I created other two router-outlet inside this one.

I got something like this.

```
   router-outlet (primary) {

       router-outlet name='info' { }

       router-outlet name='services' {

          the path I want to navigate only inside this outlet

       }
    }
```

I believe there is something wrong here:

```
<button [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { primary: { services: ['view'] }}}]"> Go to services view</button>
```

I coded a simple version on stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/router-outlet-doubt

I expect navigate to view-service component, may somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Secondary child outlet inside empty primary segment does not match

it is a known problem and not fixed yet. There is an open issue you can check at [github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14662).

There is a workaround you check on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdhh8a)

And I rewrote your code and now it works. check here [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/router-outlet-inside-empty-parent)

what I have changed so far.

1. I changed the empty parent to a router called app which refer to the `BudgetsComponent` as it is workaround for the problem.
2. Change the view routerLink as follows

   `<button [routerLink]="[{outlets: {services: ['view']}}]"> Go to services view</button>`

   where services is the outlet name and view is the routing path.